# Load balancing two web servers with ultra monkey

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, cluster

In 2006 a company I was working with setup two load balancers to balance traffic between two web servers.  We used ultra monkey to do so.

I'm hoping to do the same now.

My question:

- Would anyone recommend using ultra monkey to balance traffic between two linux boxes running apache?
- Are there other linux-based alternatives which have since proven to be better for this task?
- Would you still install debian sarge on a load balancer given it's age?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultra Monkey was essentially packaged ipvs.  It hasn't been updated in a while.  I suspect partially because ipvs was merged into the mainline kernel.

You can still use ipvs, ipvsadm, ldirectord and all that fun stuff for Layer 4 switching in Linux.  LVS is my preferred solution but there are definitely alternative architectures depenending on your needs.  These include HAProxy, Nginx, and Pound among others.  Nginx is quite popular as well for highly available Web architectures.

- [HA Proxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)
- [Pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound)
- [Nginx](http://nginx.org/)
- [Linux Virtual Server (LVS)](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Check out haproxy http://haproxy.1wt.eu

Comment: Hi, this looks really good, thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Apache's mod_proxy extension [mod_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) for a number of years. I find it far easy to set up. Also, since I use Apache for the web servers I am already familiar with the technology. You still want to have a fail over for the lb server, so I peer it with another using HA (Heartbeat).